# Reference control by fx:id

Tags: java, javafx, controls, scenebuilder

I have a calendar screen I have designed for class using JavaFX and Scene Builder.
[image]

The part where I've placed the number is a label and the part that, currently, says "None", is a button.  I want to reference the value in the Label when I select the Button so that I can display the Appointments for the user for that day.

Is there a way to reference a control by by the FX:ID string name so that I can do this?  The Label is called lblDayOfTheWeekxx and the button is called btnAppointmentxx, where xx is the value from 01 to 42.

This is what I have tried for changing the value.  It's just a test where I'm trying to turn the value of the first button to "DONE".

```
    @FXML
void handleDayChosen(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
//            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
//            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/Views/FormMain.fxml"));
//            Parent myView = loader.load();
//            Scene myScene = new Scene(myView);
//           Label lbl =  (Label) myScene.lookup("#lblDateOfMonth01");

//            Label myLblField = (Label)myView.FindControl("txtField" + 1);
//            lbl.setText("DONE");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/Views/FormMain.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Button foo = (Button)loader.getNamespace().get("lblAppointments01");

        foo.setText("DONE");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I'm new to Java so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance,

Bill

---

This is what I finally came up with.  I know it isn't *pretty* but it works.

```
            GridPane gpCal = this.gpCalendar;
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 7; i++) {
            int row = i * 2;
            for (int col = 1; col <= 7; col++) {
                int pos = ((i-1)*7)+col;
                lblDay[pos] = new Label();
                lblDay[pos].setText("");
                lblDay[pos].setPrefSize(100, 20);
                lblDay[pos].setText(String.valueOf(col) + ", " + String.valueOf(row));
                gpCal.add(lblDay[pos], col, row);
            }

            row++;
            for (int col = 0; col <= 6; col++) {
                int pos = ((i-1)*7)+col;
                btnAppts[pos] = new Button();
                btnAppts[pos].setText("");
                btnAppts[pos].setPrefSize(100, 100);
                btnAppts[pos].setText(String.valueOf(col) + ", " + String.valueOf(row));
                gpCal.add(btnAppts[pos], col, row);
            }

        }
```

Now for the easy part of formatting the buttons and labels to kind of match below.

Thanks for the help,

Bill

Comment: You can create a DayNode that have the Button and the Label in it. That may be too much for your project. You could have a map that maps the `Label` to it's `Button`.

Comment: You’re creating all these labels and buttons in FXML? It would seem to be a much better choice to create them in Java (then the solution to your question is trivial).

Comment: Thanks Sedrick.  I'll have a look.

James.  How else would I create the buttons without FXML?  I'm not sure how it helps.  I'll start Googling and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIs like this do not lend themselves at all well to FXML. It is usually much easier, and way less code, to create a UI like this using Java. That way you can create the button and label in a loop, and add a different event handler to each:

```
int numDays = 30 ; // in real life this comes from the month and year
GridPane calendarPane = ...; // can be a @FXML-injected variable if needed

for (int i = 1 ; i <= numDays ; i++) {
    Label dayLabel = new Label(Integer.toString(i));
    Button button = new Button("None");
    // set styles, etc
    int day = i ;
    button.setOnAction(e -> processButtonPress(button, dayLabel, day));
    VBox vbox = new VBox(dayLabel, button);
    int row = getRowForDay(i);
    int col = getColumnForDay(i);
    calendarPane.add(vbox, col, row);
}

// ...

private void handleDayChosen(Button button, Label label, int dayOfMonth) {
    // whatever you need here...
    label.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
    button.setText("Done");
}
```

Obviously you can still use FXML for the surrounding UI if you want, and just put the loop above in the controller's `initialize()` method. But this is clearly better than the 100+ lines of FXML plus 60 different variables in the controller to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I have probably butchered what you have provided me but it got me on the right track.  Thank you James for your help.